# Best way to implement poster background image in video tag

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hello fellow stackers,

Firstly some background, my video wasn't functional on every device and browser so I wanted to compensate by displaying an image when the video didn't play, I tried implementing the poster attribute:

```
<video autoplay poster="http://kadeem.london/Image/kadeem-bg.jpg>
```

But it just didn't look nice. I then implemented some css:

```
 video{
       background:transparent url('http://kadeem.london/Image/kadeem-bg.jpg');
   -webkit-background-size:cover; 
   -moz-background-size:cover; 
   -o-background-size:cover; 
   background-size:cover; 

 }
```

It worked fine when, for example, a visitor viewed the website on an old mobile device, and rather than finding a black screen, was greeted with a nice cover photo of me. However when the video did eventually play on a desktop for example, the image displays just a second before the video loads and is thus not very appealing. You can view the live example of this [here](http://kadeem.london). Is there a way for this concept to become totally fluid, so the image hides when the video is functional?

Please find below the HTML5 and CSS.

Thankyou in advance.

```css
 .Intro-Video {
     position: relative;
     z-index: 9999;
     width: 100%;
     display: block;
     background-color: #fff;
     -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
     overflow: hidden;
 }

 @media (max-width: 600px){
  .Intro-Video{
   background-image: url(http://kadeem.london/Image/kadeem-bg.jpg);
   width: 100%;
   background-size:cover;
  }
 }
 .video-box {
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     position: relative;
 }
  @media (max-width: 600px){
   .video-box{
    visibility: hidden;
   }
  }
 #video-container {
     height:100%;
     width:100%;
     overflow: hidden;
 }

   @media (max-width: 600px){
   #video-container{
    visibility: visible;
   }
  }

 video {
     position:absolute;
     z-index:0;
 }
 video.fillWidth {
     width: 100%;
 }

 video{
     background:transparent url('http://kadeem.london/Image/kadeem-bg.jpg') no-repeat 0 0; 
   -webkit-background-size:cover; 
   -moz-background-size:cover; 
   -o-background-size:cover; 
   background-size:cover; 
 
 }

@media (max-width:600px){
 video{visibility:hidden;
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="Intro-Video">
<div class="video-box">
<div id="video-container">
<video autoplay class="fillWidth">
<source src="http://kadeem.london/Video/Trailer.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
</video>
<div class="Kadeem-Logo">
<img src="http://kadeem.london/Image/KL_wall.png" alt="Kadeem Logo" title="Kadeem Logo">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would use Modernizr to check for HTML5 video support before the page loads and chose to either show or hide the image based on that.

Comment: Ok, thank you will look into that.